# How to transfer file to server using maven

Tags: java, maven, ant, webserver

Once maven creates a WAR file (with `mvn package`) I would like to somehow transfer the war file onto another server and then execute a command on the server to deploy the war to tomcat. I am connected to the destination Windows 2008 Server via VPN. I can also ping the destination server while vpn'd in from my local machine.

Is there a way to do this transfer of the war from my local computer to windows 2008 server? Would I need to install something additionally on the windows server?

Answer (score 2):

This [blog entry](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/) details how to use the Maven Tomcat plugin to do this.

> Issue “mvn tomcat:deploy” to package your project in a WAR file, and
>   deploy it to Tomcat server. To verify it, just access to the Tomcat’s
>   manager page and make sure “/mkyongWebApp” path is existed.

Basically you configure Tomcat to accept a remote deployment, configure your `settings.xml` with your Tomcat credentials, and set up the Tomcat Maven plugin with the hostname/port etc of your Tomcat server (phew!)

Comment: hm now how do i configure tomcat for remote deployment

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but none of them are ideal.   I would personally discourage the use of Maven as a deployment or "devops" tool.   If you really need to do this there's a good chance that your requirements are going to evolve and become more complicated as your application develops.   Why not just start with CFEngine, Chef, Puppet, or other tools?

Warning aside, you could do the following:

1. Deploy with scp - The Maven Deploy Plugin can scp a file to a server.   This overrides the real purpose of a deployment in Maven, but it will work.   (Again the downside here is that you'll be overriding the real way that Maven was designed to work)   For this to work you may need to explicitly add the SCP wagon provider, it used to be present by default, but it was removed.
2. Use Cargo to manipulate whatever server you use - http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin